# Hosts file autocomment (self-report) all entries that I add

Tags: laravel, hosts

My Hosts file looks like:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   ingeniaticupct.ddns.net
```

I am working with Laravel. Every 1 hour approximately (without touch PC) (or always when I restart Homestead, or I do any change on Laravel files, etc...) Hosts file looks like:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
#      192.168.10.10    ingeniaticupct.ddns.net
```

Ergo, my domain `ingeniaticupct.ddns.net` is autocommented (self-reported) (`#      192.168.10.10   ingeniaticupct.ddns.net`) and I do not understand why. I have been searching in several sites but I have not found solution yet.

Hope if you could help me.

Thank you all.

Comment: That’s most likely some kind of security application trying to protect your machine. Might be Bitdefender, according to https://superuser.com/questions/1018133/windows-10-hosts-file-entries-been-commented-out, but there’s probably other programs that do this as well.

Comment: Thank you! This is Solved! If you want, answer me and I will select your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ergo, my domain `ingeniaticupct.ddns.net` is autocommented (self-reported) (`#      192.168.10.10 ingeniaticupct.ddns.net`) and I do not understand why.

That’s most likely some kind of security application trying to protect your machine (from malware that would simply change or add entries in there, trying to redirect your requests for popular sites to their own servers.)

Might be Bitdefender, according to [windows 10 hosts file entries been commented out](https://superuser.com/questions/1018133/windows-10-hosts-file-entries-been-commented-out) on superuser.com; but there’s probably other programs that do this as well.